# Add Items to ComboBox Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have been working with WPF all of 2 days, coming from ASP.NET so bear with me!

I am populating a ComboBox with xml filenames from a directory and adding a icon to each item. I have everything working just fine but I am wondering if there is a "better", more "efficient" way of doing this. As I stated, I am just getting started with WPF and I want to go about things the "right" way. My working code is below, can or should I be going about this a different way? Thanks in advance for any pointers!

```
<ComboBox Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,138,0,0" Name="cmbFiles" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" //>
```

```
private void FillSrFileCombo()
{
    string[] dirFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\TestFiles", "*.xml");

    foreach (string datei in dirFiles)
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(datei);

        System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel stkPanel = new StackPanel();
        stkPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        cmbFiles.Items.Add(stkPanel);

        System.Windows.Controls.Image cboIcon = new Image();
        BitmapImage bitMap = new BitmapImage();
        bitMap.BeginInit();
        bitMap.UriSource = new Uri(@"tag.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        bitMap.EndInit();
        cboIcon.Source = bitMap;
        cboIcon.Height = 15;
        stkPanel.Children.Add(cboIcon);

        System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock cboText = new TextBlock();
        cboText.Text = " - " + fileName;
        stkPanel.Children.Add(cboText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have answered a similar question an hour ago see here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637514/add-usercontrol-to-listbox-wpf.

I will recap the most important parts here based on your example

In the XAML you need to create a "DataTemplate", that is the XAML representation of your file object - in your case an image + file name. You can create this Datatemplate as a resource and assign it to your ComboBox or simply create it in the combobox if you don't plan to reuse it

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
      <Image Source="{Binding FileImage}" Height="16" Width="16"/>
      <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding FileName}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In your Codebehind, you need to create a structure that represets the data you want to present in your combobox - let's say a "FileInfo" class. The FileInfo class needs to expose the "FileImage" and "FileName" as properties so you can bind to them (as seen above).
Next, you need to create a collection of such objects in the code-behind of the xaml you put your ComboBox in. The collection needs to be an ObservableCollection.

So you would have smth like this:

```
public class FileInfo
 {
     public ImageSource FileImage { get; set; }
     public string FileName { get; set; }
 }
```

and then in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

public ObservableCollection Files { get; private set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    Files = new ObservableCollection();

```
foreach (string datei in dirFiles)
{
   var fName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(datei);
   BitmapImage bitMap = new BitmapImage();
   bitMap.BeginInit();
   bitMap.UriSource = new Uri(@"tag.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
   bitMap.EndInit();
   Files.Add(new FileInfo(){FileName=fName, FileImage = bitMap});
}
```

}

You will still need to read a lot about *why* this will work. I recomend reading about DataTemplates DataBinding, ObservableCollection and in the end, read about MVVM, a pattern that ties all this stuff nicely and allows you to harness all the WPF power and decouple yor logic from the UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot AlexDrenea! I really appreciate the help! With a couple tweaks, your code works like a charm and I will definitely look into your recommended reading. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

One way that you should consider for WPF/Silverlight/WP7 apps is the [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

In this instance you would have a view model containing the collection of items for your `ComboBox`, and you would use a binding expression to set the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox`. You would then [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) the `ComboBox` to display your item images.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx), the only C# code you should need here is to get the files (even though you could also do that in XAML using something like an [`ObjectDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for the response, would it be too much trouble for you to whip up an example of your suggestion accomplishing the same thing I have above? I have seen code examples of what you have suggested and forgive me but it just seems to over complicate things and require the writing of more code?? I may be way off here and this is why I'm asking :)

Comment: @user1035765: It usually requires *less* code *and* it's more readable. I can't provide code right now as i am about to head out, may post some in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks H.B., I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @user1035765: It looks like you do not necessarily need it anymore. I'd remark though that as the image is always the same you can set the `Source` directly in XAML instead, you could also create it just once as resource and then reference it in the template using [`StaticResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx) to not waste time and memory. To get the hyphen in the bound `TextBlock` you could use `Binding.StringFormat` or just create another `TextBlock`. As i said, i would probably only retrieve the files in code, everything else is easily done in XAML.